# Wayfarer Accepted pokestop is not live

Tags: pokemon-go

I submitted 2 pokestops on 1 may 2021 and all 2 pokestops got approval in my niantic account, after 24 hours when I checked whether they are live in game or not, I have noticed that the 2nd pokestop nomination is live but the first pokestop nomination, even after being accepted, is missing in the game.

I got an email for the 2nd nomination being live but didn't get any email of first one being live even when it is approved in my niantic wayfarer account.

So what do you guys think? will my first nomination which is accepted but not yet appeared in game will appear sometime later? Or it has been approved but will not come live because of some unknown reason?

The distance between the pokestops are about 150 meters

If the first nomination does not come live in game even after being accepted in wayfarer , can I submit a new nomination of the same place again?

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First up, use [Ingress Intel](https://intel.ingress.com) to check if the waypoint has actually gone live. If it doesn't appear there, it *probably* hasn't been accepted (which would explain why you don't have an email yet). It's also worth checking that there isn't a similar waypoint in that location where it might have been marked as a duplicate.

You say the distance between the two submitted waypoints is 150 metres, so there shouldn't be any duplicate/proximity issues, but if there are *other* waypoints in the vicinity they can cause problems. Waypoints that are within 20 metres of another waypoint on submission automatically get marked as a duplicate of the closest other waypoint even if they get approved, and waypoints that are in the same size 17 S2 cell as an existing waypoint will only go live in Ingress, and not in Pokemon Go.

For example, take the following screenshot of my local area, with size 17 S2 cells marked. You can see that in each cell with a waypoint, a pokestop (or a gym) exists, but in the cells marked with the "1" and "2", a second waypoint in that cell only became a portal, and does not exist in Pokemon Go

[image]

If this is not the case in your area, then there's a few possibilities. Waypoints are only synchronised to Pokemon Go once each weekday, at around 6:40pm UTC. Since you say that the waypoint was marked "accepted" on the 2nd of May 2021, this should not be affecting you, but not receiving an email means that it might not have actually been accepted yet. This email should occur whenever acceptance starts, *not* upon synchronisation to PoGo, so you should always receive an email before it appears in-game.

> can I submit a new nomination of the same place again?

If none of the notes above apply to you (that is, the waypoint is marked as "accepted", is not live in Ingress, is not within 20 metres of another waypoint, and you haven't received an email after a few days), then yes, the best course of action is likely to just resubmit it.

Comment: I used ingress, same happened, 2nd pokestop(portal) is live but first one is not live even it shows 'accepted' in wayfarer.  I don't know whether anyone else had nominated the same place before me but, when I nominated the 1st one, there were no pokestops or gyms because my hometown is deserted according to Pokemon go so duplicate should not be the issue. I don't have any idea about the s17 cells because I don't have any reliable map, but wait, which map are you using? I need it. And the nomination was accepted on 5th may, not 2nd.That means, they have bannered it as accepted while it isnt?

Comment: Oh I recently checked s2 cells level 17, none of the pokestops interfere each others cell.

Comment: The map I'm using for the above screenshot is only for my local area, however you can use an Ingress Intel viewer called "IITC" with the plugin "PoGo Tools" to see S2 cells over the Intel map of any region of your choice. Unfortunately this doesn't show you which waypoints have been synced to PoGo, but it should be serviceable for your uses. My guess would be that Wayfarer is just displaying it as accepted incorrectly. Give it a week or so and if you still have no more information and Wayfarer still says "accepted" then it's probably worth resubmitting.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind support :)